# Access performance counters for ASP.NET Web App in Microsoft Azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, database-connection, performancecounter

I'm working on a diagnostics tool which needs to monitor active/free/pooled database connections from the web application side (asp.net) published to the Azure as a Web App. It's important to monitor from the client side because I'm targeting certain issues with connection pooling under app load.

I found [all the required information](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/CMouli/monitoring-database-connections-using-performance-counters/) in the performance counter category `.NET Data Provider for SqlServer` which I was able to access locally and track all the required data.

Unfortunately, once I published the code to the Azure I got the following exception: `UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied`

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.InternalGetValue(String name, Object defaultValue, Boolean doNotExpand, Boolean checkSecurity)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue(String name)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceMonitor.GetData(String item)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(String item)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String machine, String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCounterInstances(String categoryName, String machineName)
```

Is there any way I can access performance counter for my Web App instance in Azure environment?

Answer (score 2):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters:

> Performance counters aren't available for Azure Web Apps. But you can [send Azure Diagnostics to Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters).

Cloud Services or VMs would be the workaround - not really a *workaround*, more like a different game, i know.

You can definitely use http://azureserviceprofiler.com with App Service, but i don't know if you get the granularity you're looking for. It's pretty good though, try it.

Comment: there is no issue with 'sending and collecting stats', there is an issue to gather that stats. ADO.NET SqlConnection Pool size, active, free, etc is available only via Performance Counters (AFAIK), so the question here is how to access ADO.NET SqlConnection Pool stats in Azure Environment.